# Как выделить главный домен из URL?

Tags: vb.net

Например, есть адрес `http://yandex.ru/balbla` надо определить домен `http://yandex.ru`.

Comment: *Ещё один человек, делающий браузер на VB? XD*

Comment: ага я пробую прсто

Comment: Используя элемент WebBrowser вы не делаете практически ни чего нового и используете движёк IE...

Comment: лучше сначала выучить русский язык, а потом уже браться за ВБ

Comment: спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте строковые функции, например, `http://` можно отсекать через

```
Str = Mid(Str, 8, Str.Length)
```

Это если Вам именно домен нужен...

А дальше, в цикле, тем же **`Mid`**'ом *отсекайте* по одному знаку и конкатенируете их к выходной строке до тех пор, пока не дойдете до первого же "`/`".

Как-то так...

```
Dim i As Integer = 1
Do
    OutString += Mid(Str, i, 1)
    i+=1
Loop Untill Mid(Str, i, 1) = "/"
```